# science fiction book where nano technology is everywhere and a man is married to a computer program

Tags: story-identification

I rented a book from the library where there is nanotechnology everywhere, a substance that coats everything and can by ordered about at will.

A man is married to a computer program and the two have children. The computer wife is captured and is placed in a prison where she is forced to solve math problems at the max of her processing power. At the end there is a jeep(?) that is self-propelled and sentient that is travelling around the countryside on Earth.

This book is no longer at the library nor do they have any records from the time I rented the book, about 8 years ago.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like Superluminal by Tony Daniel.

An excellent book, but unfortunately so far as I know it is part of a never finished multi-volume novel.